# how to redirect from sub route to major route in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a question about react router dom. in my `App.js` component i have some routes that includes :  `"/",  "/:userId/profile", "/chat", ...`  .  the `Profile.js` component that its address is `"/:userId/profile"`.  in there again i have some routes to render some pages (components) . in the `Profile.js` top of all routes i set `Header.js` component that contain information about user like name and picture, ...  . in `Header.js` component i have button that i want to navigate to `"/:userId/create-post"` routes and this routes i defined in `App.js` component. how can i redirect from nested routes to major route in `App.js` ??

in `App.js` component :

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router basename="/">
      <Navigation />

      <main className="app">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact render={() => <Posts />} />
          <Route path="/:userId/profile" exact render={() => <Profile />} />
          <Route path="/chat" exact render={() => <Chat />} />
          <Route path="/suggested" exact render={() => <Suggested />} />
          <Route path="/explore" exact render={() => <Explore />} />
          <Route path="/auth" exact render={() => <Auth />} />

          <Route
            path="/:userId/create-post"
            exact
            render={() => <CreatePost />}
          />

          <Redirect to="/" />
        </Switch>
      </main>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

in `Profile.js` component :

```
const UserProfile = props => {
  return (
    <Section className="section">
      <Router primary={false}>
        <ProfileHeader user={props.user} />
        <ProfileNavigate userId={props.user.userId} />

        <Section className="section">
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path="/:userId/profile/posts"
              exact
              render={() => <ProfilePostsList userPosts={props.userPosts} />}
            />

            <Route
              path="/:userId/profile/saved"
              exact
              render={() => <ProfileSavedList userPosts={props.userPosts} />}
            />

            <Route
              path="/:userId/profile/tagged"
              exact
              render={() => <ProfileTaggedList userPosts={props.userPosts} />}
            />

            <Redirect
              from={`/${props.user.userId}/profile`}
              to={`/${props.user.userId}/profile/posts`}
            />
          </Switch>
        </Section>
      </Router>
    </Section>
  );
};

export default UserProfile;
```

in `Profile-Header.js` component :

```
<Button
  className="weight btn-create"
  onClick={navigateHandler}
>
  Create Post
</Button>
```

event handler :

```
  const navigateHandler = () => {
    history.push(`/${props.user.userId}/create-post`);
  };
```

Comment: So I guess the push to `\`/${props.user.userId}/create-post\`` isn't working? Looks like the second `Router` wrapping your `UserProfile` component is the nearest router context, but the route you want to get to is on the `Router` in `App`. Remove the "nested" router.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese yes i think you'r right but if i remove the nested router in `Profile.js` all routes in there can't work fine dude.

Comment: You really only need one router in your app. If I also had to guess, it stopped working when you removed the nested router because the root router matches only ***exact*** path `"/:userId/profile"`, so any sub-routes with that path-prefix won't match.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese thanks buddy i'm working on it to fix  this issue